# Dismiss UIPickerView when selected row is tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I'm using UIPickerView to let the user pick from few options, when I show the picker I scroll to the last selected row.

When user select a row I want to always dismiss the picker (even if user tap the already selected row), I dismiss the picker in the `didSelectRow` method.

The problem is, if the user reselect the selected row the `didSelectRow` method doesn't get called so I can't dismiss the picker..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create a subclass of UIPickerView and override the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    // dismiss the picker view here, either directly, or you could notifiy
    // the delegate with a custom message:
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pickerViewShouldDismiss:)]) {
        [self.delegate pickerViewShouldDismiss:self];
    }
}
```

Or you could add a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the `UIPickerView`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                 action:@selector(pickerViewTapped];
[pickerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
```

And then:

```
- (void)pickerViewTapped {
    // dismiss the picker.
}
```

I'm not 100% sure though this won't interfere with the way `UIPickerView` handles taps.

Comment: No easy solution without subclassing?

Comment: Tap gesture won't work because there is already a tap gesture built inside the pickerView. You will have to play around with the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods to separate the two and respond to the custom tap gesture differently.